# Segmentation Fault when using strupr(...) with GCC compiler

Tags: c

When run following code after compiling on gcc,I get segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct emp
    {
        char *n;
        int age;
    };

    struct emp e1={"David",23};
    struct emp e2=e1;
    strupr(e2.n);
    printf("%s\n%s\n",e1.n,e2.n);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals like `"David"` cannot be altered, which is what you're doing when you call `strupr`. You should copy the string (e.g. with `strdup`) before.

Comment: Worth adding that there's a GCC warning option to spot this problem, -Wwrite-strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a seg fault because

```
struct emp e1={"David",23};
```

"David" resides in data, so it is a read-only, or const, string.

When you

```
strupr(e2.n);
```

You are trying to modify that same const string.

Working code:

```
struct emp e2;
e2.age = e1.age;
e2.n = (char *)malloc(SOME_SIZE);
strcpy(e2.n, e1.n); //here you copy the contents of the read-only string to newly allocated memory
strupr(e2.n);
printf(...);
free(e2.n);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing `struct emp e1={"David",23};` you have made "David" a string literal, which is read-only in nature. In the executable it is stored in the `.rodata` or equivalent section of the executable, which is read-only. by the `strupr ()` you are attempting to modify this read-only data, and thus a segmentation fault.